# Downside of using image vs global memory?

Tags: opencl

I have a kernel that processes RGB images. Currently,
I take each channel one by one, and run the same kernel on that channel

The kernel input is a global memory buffer: data is moved in chunks from the global
buffer into local memory for processing, then stored into another global
buffer as output.

I was thinking of refactoring this to store all three channels in an RGBA
buffer, and operate on all three channels at the same time, using vector
operations. I understand that images have better spatial caching.

Is there any disadvantage to this refactor? I realize that I will have to reduce
the number of pixels per chunk, because I will now have three times the amount
of data.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions: How is your RGB data laid out? Planar or interleaved? Also, what hardware are you targeting? Different hardware will have differing characteristics. Finally, how much ALU does your filter use? A big complex filter or a small, simple filter?

Comment: Thanks, user2746401.  I can choose what format to use - I suppose interleaved is the way to go if I switch to image. Currently it is planar. Also, I am going to be targetting AMD Hawaii GPUS ; 290X for example. Also, the filter is big and complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, modern GPUs are working with images very well, because originally they were designed to do so. Unless you are using some specific hardware, which isn't good with Image data structure, such refactoring is a good idea (IMO).

Changing the amount of data, that every WI or WG process, doesn't mandatory lead to performance decrease - algorithm changes may influence performance in unpredictable way. So, to make conclusions, careful benchmarks are needed.

If you are targeting specific hardware, using SDK tools is always a good idea. Performance analyzers can give useful statistics & optimization hints (such as register spilling, cache hit rate, utilization percentage, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, Roman. I am doing a discrete wavelet transform: columns are transformed first, then rows, so it is not a simple convolution-type algorithm.  I am working alone on this project, and I am an opencl beginner: do you have time for a quick code review to flag any obvious errors on my part?  https://github.com/boxerab/ocldwt is the project. Currently, on windows, using intel processor as device, it is no faster than serial code on CPU, so a bit disappointing. But I know it can be improved....